# How to exclude ApplicationContextInitializers in @SpringBootTest?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I'm trying to run a `@SpringBootTest` in a "clean" context without having `MyApplicationContextInitializer` executed.

The `MyApplicationContextInitializer` is included inside the `spring.factories` file in a `compile-scope` dependency like this:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer=\
com.eremic.myapp.MyApplicationContextInitializer
```

**Test class:**

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestContext.class)
public class UsersControllerTest {}
```

**Test config:**

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
public class TestContext {}
```

Is there a way to exclude `MyApplicationContextInitializer` from `@SpringBootTest`?

I've already tired with excludeFilters `@ComponentScan.Filters`, but it has no effect on ApplicationContextInitializer.

Also, I've tried to annotate `TestContext` with `@SpringBootApplication` and to limit component scanning with `scanBasePackages` and/or to use `exclude = MyApplicationContextInitializer.class` but it has no effect too.

So far the only way to prevent `MyApplicationContextInitializer` from executing inside `@SpringBootTest` is to remove the maven dependency in which the `MyApplicationContextInitializer` is declared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not currently a way to filter `ApplicationContextInitializer` classes loaded from factories. To do that on a per-test level you'd need to use a custom annotation that uses a different `SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper`. The bootstrapper would need to return a `SpringBootContextLoader` that filtered the initializers. Feel free to raise an issue and we can add some protected method to `SpringBootContextLoader` for you to override.

Comment: Thank you @phil-webb, I've opened an issue a few weeks ago but it's marked as 'question' and closed https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/11457

Comment: Now reopened and targeted to 2.0.0.RC2

Comment: Is there an example for implementing this solution ?

Answer (score 0):

For those who are interested in how exclusions of `ApplicationContextInitializer` were made possible in SpringBoot (by @phil_webb).

You have to extend `org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader` and override `getInitializers` method:

```java
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer;
import org.springframework.test.context.MergedContextConfiguration;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Custom context loader for modifying {@code ApplicationContextInitializer}'s
 */
public class CustomInitializersContextLoader extends SpringBootContextLoader {

    @Override
    protected List<ApplicationContextInitializer<?>> getInitializers(MergedContextConfiguration config,
                                                                     SpringApplication application) {
        // modify list of initializers however you need
        return super.getInitializers(config, application);
    }

}
```

And then you can enable this loader with `org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration`:

```java
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;

@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(loader = CustomInitializersContextLoader.class)
public abstract class DemoTest {
    // regular tests
}
```